# Spring Data and @Transactional does not rollback when there are multiple saves

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, hikaricp

I use:

- Spring data (4.x)
- HikariCP
- Hibernate (I use EntityManager)

Consider the following repositories:

```
public interface TestModelRepository extends JpaRepository<TestModel, Long> {
}

public interface TestModelRepository2 extends JpaRepository<TestModel2, Long> {
}
```

and the following service:

```
@Service
static class Svc {

    @Autowired
    private TestModelRepository modelRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TestModelRepository2 modelRepository2;

    @Transactional
    public void insertWithException() {
        assertThat(TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus()).isNotNull();

        modelRepository.save(new TestModel("any"));

        modelRepository2.save(new TestModel2("unique"));
        modelRepository2.save(new TestModel2("unique"));
    }

}
```

The second save in repository 2 throws DataIntegrityViolationException because the provided value is not unique. Transaction should rollback everything in this method as it is annotated with @Transactional, hovewer it does not.

TestModel and one of TestModel2 are persisted. Actually they are persisted to the database just after each save() call, so the values are inserted into the database even if the @Transactional method did not complete yet (I verified it by placing a breakpoint and logging into the database). It looks to me like autocommit is set to true, hovewer I set it to false (in HikariCP config).

Here is my java-based configuration (fragments):

```
@Bean
PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    return transactionManager;
}


@Bean
JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    adapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
    adapter.setDatabasePlatform(MySQL5Dialect.class.getName());

    return adapter;
}


LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(packagesToScan);
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(properties);
```

Main question: **why the transaction does not rollback everything?**

Additional questions:

- when the data should be commited to the database? When the transaction is commited or anytime?
- is the connection kept during the whole transaction, or can it be returned to the pool in the middle of transaction and then another connection is requested if needed?
- Spring Data doesn't require @Transactional on repositories, what are the transaction parameters then (propagation and isolation)?

Comment: You may have `autocommit` on the connection or in the db config.  I also noticed you're using mysql.  Make sure your schema and tables are InnoDB not MyISAM

Comment: My tables were MyISAM, setting them to InnoDB immediately solved the issue! Thank you so much! If you'd like, post an answer and I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: cheers!  glad it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have autocommit on the connection or in the db config. I also noticed you're using mysql. Make sure your schema and tables are InnoDB not MyISAM

Comment: It was InnoDB isue. My tables were in MyISAM and this engine does not support transactions. Thanks one more time!

Comment: As a note: connection auto-commit is a red herring - when executing a transaction declared with `@Transactional`, springs saves the connection auto-commit flag, sets it to false, executes the transaction, and restores the flag